# What is the correct location for a custom action in the "Actions" group of the Ribbon in a list Display Form?

Tags: ribbon, custom-actions

I'm trying to add a couple custom actions to the Ribbon for a particular list.  I'm using `ContentType` as the registration type to target the specific list.

I have one that shows up correctly in the "Actions" group in the list *view*, but the one I want added to the Display Form is not showing up (and yes, the item is of the correct content type).

For the one that's working on the list view, for the `CustomAction` itself I have

```
Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView"
```

and for the `CommandUIDefintion` I have

```
Location="Ribbon.ListItem.Actions.Controls._children"
```

For the one I'm trying to get in the Display Form, for the `CustomAction` I have

```
Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.ListForm"
```

and for the `CommandUIDefintion` I have

```
Location="Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Actions.Controls._children"
```

Looking into CMDUI.XML I can see that that appears to be the correct group ID, I set my sequence number high enough that it should be after all of the ones I see in the CMDUI.XML file (even though they don't all show up in the Ribbon), and I set the template alias to `"o2"` because that's what most of the ones in that group are... so... do I not have the right location?

How can I get a button in the "Actions" group in the Display Form?